# Using Ruby, grab value from HTML string inside a JSON response

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, string

I have searched what I can and I don't seem to be finding the answer I need. Granted I may not be wording it properly. I have tried using `.find` or even `.rindex` to count backwards, but no such luck. The value I receive from the JSON looks something like this:

```
"AdditionalData":"<Data><Entry Key=\"utm_campaign\" Value=\"j2c\" /> 
<Entry Key=\"utm_medium\" Value=\"cpc\" /><Entry Key=\"utm_source\" 
Value=\"j2c\" /><Entry Key=\"job_id\" Value=\"300_xxxx_10703\" /></Data>"
```

I need to be able to grab the value for the key "job_id", so the "300_xxxx_11233". This value will change per object returned by the JSON response. Any help would be appreciated, and please let me know if this is already out there and I just missed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the response format remains the same with every request, you could use a plain regexp expression to fetch your data, even without parsing JSON. Example:

```
response = "<Data><Entry Key=\"utm_campaign\" Value=\"j2c\" /><Entry Key=\"utm_medium\" Value=\"cpc\" /><Entry Key=\"utm_source\" Value=\"j2c\" /><Entry Key=\"job_id\" Value=\"300_xxxx_10703\" /></Data>"
match = response.match(%r{job_id\\?"\s+Value=\\?"(.+)\\?"}i)
match[1] if match # => "300_xxxx_10703"
```

If the response format can change (for example, if the order of the attributes of `Entry` element can change), then you need to parse JSON and use some HTML parser, such as [Nokigiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri), to fetch required attrbute. Code example:

```
parsed_response = JSON.parse(response)
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(parsed_response['AdditionalData'])

job_id = nil
doc.css('Entry').each do |el|
  if el['Key'] == 'job_id'
    job_id = el['Value']
    break
  end
end
```